# How to return multiple nameId formats in OneLogin Ruby metadata xml?

Tags: ruby, saml, onelogin

**Question**

Can OneLogin's Ruby gem be configured to return multiple name id formats in our applications saml metadata xml?

**Context:**

We are a service provider that use's Onelogin's Ruby gem for SAML SSO and we have a customer who is integrating their ADFS 2.0 with our application. We have set this up successfully and have many other customers using ADFS, however, this one customer is running into trouble due to something to do with the nameID format configurations.

When the user gets to the ACS url on our server, we see the error: `"The status code of the Response was not Success, was Requester => InvalidNameIDPolicy"`. In the ADFS Event Log of the customer, we see `"Actual NameID properties: null."`

We have triple checked that the claims in the customer's Relaying Party Trust are proper with a claim of the AD attribute EmailAddress mapping to an outgoing claim of Email Address and then an additional transform claim of Email Address to outgoing claim of NameID with format Email.

This configuration is consistent with previous customers who haven't had issues and also with the customer's other relaying party trusts which are successfully configured with other service providers.

We looked at other service provider metadata xml and we noticed that they return multiple name id formats. For instance, they have SSO with Zoom and Zoom's metadata xml shows nameid formats for: emailAddress, transient, persistent, unspecified, and X509SubjectName.

My question is: Can OneLogin's Ruby gem be configured to return multiple name id formats in our applications saml metadata xml? There does not appear to be documentation on this via the gem: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml

Comment: What version of ADFS are you using?  Is it 2019?

Comment: ADFS 2.0. Not sure of the year

Comment: I had a call this morning from an ADFS (Windows Server 2019) customer, they're getting the same error message, "InvalidNameIDPolicy".  I'm wondering if it is related to 2019 - it would appear there have been some changes.

Comment: Your question is premature for SO. We expect to see where your researched this, and if it didn't help, why? If it did, what code did you write to test it? If you didn't why? If you did and it didn't help, why? Currently, we have very little to work with to help you, and without code or a repeatable problem we can't create a concise solution, which is what SO is about.

Comment: @theTinMan. If you read to the end of the question, there is a very clear, answerable question at the end of this. The preamble is to explain the context and use case of what I am trying to do. If the question needs to be edited to make the direct question more clear to the reader, that is a fair critique. If you want SAML Tracer logs that is also fair, but there is a diminishing return on including logs or code to make a question clear and answerable which is why they are not initially included. But happy to oblige if a knowledgeable requester makes the ask.

Comment: "`Can OneLogin's Ruby gem be configured to return multiple name id formats in our applications saml metadata xml? Or is there other guidance on how to fix this?`" is extremely broad. Again, the question from the community will be, "What did you find after researching, what was tried...."

Comment: The 2nd question is broad, but the first question is highly specific. I've updated the format of the question to be more clear what I'm asking, the context, and the research I've done (searching the gem) at the bottom.